# Pass both props and observer to observed component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

How can I pass both props and a store to a Mobx `observer` component? Here is the observed component. I don't get any errors when I try to access `props.isFilterDrawerOpen` in the component

```
export interface Props {
    isFilterDrawerOpen: boolean
}

export const Dashboard = observer(({myStore, props} : {myStore: MyStore, props: PropsWithChildren<Props>}) => {
//...
});
```

However, when I try to use `Dashboard` as below:

```
            <Dashboard
              myStore={myStore}
              isFilterDrawerOpen={isFilterDrawerOpen} />
```

I get this error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ myStore: MyStore; isFilterDrawerOpen: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &amp; { myStore: MyStore; props: PropsWithChildren&lt;Props&gt;; }'.
Property 'isFilterDrawerOpen' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &amp; { myStore: MyStore; props: PropsWithChildren&lt;Props&gt;; }'.
```

I can pass `props` parameter manually like this, but I'd be nice if I can achieve the above.

```
            <Dashboard
              myStore={myStore}
              props={{isFilterDrawerOpen: isFilterDrawerOpen}} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your observer component props to have 2 props "fields": `myStore` and `props`, where props is an object of type `Props` with a `isFilterDrawerOpen` field, that's why you have to pass them as `props={{isFilterDrawerOpen: isFilterDrawerOpen}}` to not get errors. You can think of it as usual object fields, since it really is just a parameter object in your arrow function, so there's 2 fields so far.
Instead you can define it as:

```
export interface Props {
    myStore: YourStoreType
    isFilterDrawerOpen: boolean
}

export const Dashboard = observer(({myStore, isFilterDrawerOpen}: Props) =>{})
```

You can define as many props as you want and type them accordingly. You can check more examples in [Mobx React docs](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#react-integration).
You can check a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/minimal-observer-forked-chiete) here as well, where you can see observer component being created with custom Props.